# Looking for ArcView 3.0a Mac Edition?

Tags: mac, arcview-3

I have googled extensively and have emailed a few different companies but have come up with nothing. I was wondering if anyone knew where to locate a copy of ArcView 3.0a that is compatible with Mac OS? I have checked ebay etc. Is anyone aware of any place that specializes in selling used out of date software or are there any private users with it to sell.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's unrelated to GIS science

Comment: well that's just your opinion man. but anyway close it down if it doesn't meet the community standards. I tried to delete it but it would not let me.

Comment: I think the question is on-topic for this site but I downvoted it due to not showing research effort (as per the tip on the downvote button).  I think any question of less than about a paragraph leaves little room for describing prior research and risks downvotes.  Why it cannot now be deleted is explained in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Comment: The only way to acquire a copy of ArcView 3.0a is through software piracy (it is long Retired by Esri, and cannot be licensed).  This led to my closure vote.

Comment: ESRI Support by request via (login now required) http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/view/productid/25/metaid/483

Comment: The links to software are either 404 or routed to the main support page.  [End of Life announcement](http://downloads2.esri.com/support/product%20life%20cycle/other_/ArcViewGIS3xJan2008_PLC.pdf)

Comment: i was so excited for a minute, i though that they were letting people download it for free!

Answer (score 2):

If you are unable to locate a copy anywhere else then I would recommend asking its developers (Esri) if they may be able to supply you with one.

Comment: I'd be fascinated if they could, considering the 15 year gap between the software publish date and the OS creation date.  None of the operating systems on which the NeuronData UI toolkit was supported are currently in existence.  Heck, most of the ***companies*** that developed those operating systems are no longer in existence. To the best of my knowledge, all copies of the AV3 media kits have been destroyed.

Comment: @Vince I only ever saw an AV2 alpha (which was pre-Avenue) run on a Mac during a benchmark here so I wasn't a follower of its system requirements :-)  I just figured the first place I would look for a copy of ancient software would be by asking the company who developed it, especially since they are clearly still in business.  I was assuming the user had found some old working hardware and wanted to get something interesting from the same period running on it.

Comment: exactly i have an old power pc mac and am fond of arcview 3 and wanted to give it a go